# Username Password Auth Flow returning different response than expected

Tags: oauth2, restresource

I'm trying to get the access token using Salesforce Username/Password OAuth flow. I have created a connected app, provided full access in the Oauth scopes and pre-authorized System Admin profile users. I'm sending a POST request in Salesforce and added all the query parameters client_id, client_secret, username, password, grant_type. I was expecting the response body to contain the access token but ended up getting html content. Am I doing something wrong somewhere?? I thought this OAuth flow is pretty straight forward.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="visibility: visible;" lang=en-us xml:lang=en-us>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta name="description" content="Salesforce Customer Secure Login Page. Login to your Salesforce Customer Account." />
        <title>Login | Salesforce</title>
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/sfdc_210.css" />
        <style type="text/css">html{visibility: hidden;}a{color:#0070d2;}body{background-color:#F4F6F9;}#content,.container{background-color:#ffffff;}#header{color:#16325c;}body{display: table; width:100%;}#content{margin-bottom:24px;}#wrap{height:100%;}</style>
        <style type="text/css"> html { visibility: hidden; } </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">if (self == top) {document.documentElement.style.visibility = 'visible';} else {document.write = ''; top.location = self.location; setTimeout(function(){document.body.innerHTML='';}, 1);window.self.onload=function(evt){document.body.innerHTML='';};}</script>
        <script>var SFDCSessionVars={"server":"https:\/\/login.salesforce.com\/login\/sessionserver212.html","im":false,"ah":"active","save":"Save","saveOne":"Save 1 Change","sum":"#p# Saved Usernames","iaac":false,"hac":"Choose a Username","suo":"1 Saved Username","title":" | Salesforce","saveMany":"Save #p# Changes","lpt":"Login","lllbl":"Lightning Login","host":"login.salesforce.com","le":false,"heu":"Edit Username List","ic":false,"lh":false,"hidp":"Log In Using","ih":"inactive","dc":"Username removed. Click Save to Commit Changes."};</script>
        <script src="/jslibrary/SfdcSessionBase208.js"></script>
        <script src="/jslibrary/LoginHint208.js"></script>
        <script>LoginHint.hideLoginForm();</script>
        <link rel="canonical" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=us"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=nb-no" hreflang="nb-no"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=de" hreflang="de"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=tw" hreflang="zh-Hant-tw"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=ru" hreflang="ru"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=fi" hreflang="fi"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=jp" hreflang="ja-jp"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=fr" hreflang="fr"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=br" hreflang="pt-br"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=se" hreflang="sv"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=uk" hreflang="en-gb"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=ca" hreflang="en-ca"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com" hreflang="en-us"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in" hreflang="en-in"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=en-hk" hreflang="en-hk"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=kr" hreflang="ko-kr"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=cn" hreflang="zh-Hans-cn"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=mx" hreflang="es-mx"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=it" hreflang="it"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=fr-ca" hreflang="fr-ca"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=es" hreflang="es"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=ap" hreflang="en-sg"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=eu" hreflang="en"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=th" hreflang="th"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=au" hreflang="en-au"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=da-dk" hreflang="da-dk"/>
        <link rel="alternate" href="https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=nl" hreflang="nl"/>
    </head>
    <body onload="lazyload();">
        <div id="left" class="pr">
            <div id="wrap">
                <div id="main">
                    <div id="wrapper">
                        <div id="logo_wrapper" class="standard_logo_wrapper mb24">
                            <h1 style="height: 100%; display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;">
                                <img id="logo" class="standard_logo" src="/img/logo214.svg" alt="Salesforce" border="0" name="logo">
                            </h1>
                        </div>
                        <h2 id="header" class="mb12"></h2>
                        <div id="content">
                            <div id="chooser" style="display: none">
                                <div class="loginError" id="chooser_error" style="display:none;"></div>
                                <div>
                                    <span id="chooser_label" class="label"></span>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="edit" class="fr small" onclick="LoginHint.showEdit();">Edit List</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="scrollable mt8">
                                    <ul id="idlist"></ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="manager" style="display: none">
                                <div class="nonscrollable mt8">
                                    <ul id="editlist" class="mb24" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals"></ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="mt16">
                                    <button class="button primary fiftyfifty right" id="hint_save_edit" name="Save" onclick="LoginHint.saveHintEdit();">Save</button>
                                    <button class="button secondary fiftyfifty" id="hint_back_edit" name="Cancel" onclick="LoginHint.showChooser();">Cancel</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="theloginform">
                                <form name="login" method="post" id="login_form" onsubmit="handleLogin();" action="https://login.salesforce.com/" target="_top" autocomplete="off" novalidate="novalidate">
                                    <input type="hidden" id="pqs" name="pqs" value="?grant_type=password&amp;client_id=3MVG9QBLg8QGkFerS4zTdoCnaDOPl5Qm6KEYMSYQT.eNLlQpt9ox.0fG6R8tHAESMKKBlbf2b4ql_hWZbskgu&amp;client_secret=4869032460675835042&amp;username=pkonda%40cardlytics.com.dev&amp;password=AppleJack_2019"/>
                                    <fieldset style="display:none">
                                        <input type="hidden" name="un" id="un_hfid" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="width" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="height" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="hasRememberUn" value="true" />
                                        <input type="hidden" id="login_startUrl" name="startURL" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="loginURL" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="loginType" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="useSecure" value="true" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="local" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="lt" value="standard" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="qs" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="locale" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="oauth_token" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="oauth_callback" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="login" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="serverid" value="" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="QCQQ" value="null" />
                                        <input type="hidden" name="display" value="page" />
                                    </fieldset>
                                    <div id="usernamegroup" class="inputgroup">
                                        <label for="username" class="label usernamelabel">Username</label>
                                        <div id="username_container">
                                            <div id="idcard-container" class="mt8 mb16" style="display: none">
                                                <div id="idcard">
                                                    <img id="idcard-avatar" class="avatar" alt="">
                                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="clear_link" class="clearlink" onclick="LoginHint.clearExistingIdentity();">
                                                        <img alt="Log In with a Different Username" class="clearicon" src="/img/clear.png">
                                                    </a>
                                                    <span id="idcard-identity"></span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <input class="input r4 wide mb16 mt8 username" type="email" value="" name="username" id="username" aria-describedby="error">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <label for="password" class="label">Password</label>
                                    <input class="input r4 wide mb16 mt8 password" type="password" id="password" name="pw" onkeypress="checkCaps(event)" autocomplete="off"/>
                                    <div id="pwcaps" class="mb16" style="display:none">
                                        <img id="pwcapsicon" alt="Caps Lock is on." width="12"/> Caps Lock is on.
                                    </div>
                                    <input class="button r4 wide primary" type="submit" id="Login" name="Login" value="Log In" />
                                    <div class="w0 pr ln3 p16 remember">
                                        <input type="checkbox" class="r4 fl mr8" style="" id="rememberUn" name="rememberUn">
                                        <label for="rememberUn" class="fl pr db tn3">Remember me</label>
                                        <br>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <div class="w0 links bt pt16 mb20">
                                    <a id="forgot_password_link" class="fl small" href="/secur/forgotpassword.jsp?locale=us&lqs=grant_type%3Dpassword%26client_id%3D3MVG9QBLg8QGkFerS4zTdoCnaDOPl5Qm6KEYMSYQT.eNLlQpt9ox.0fG6R8tHAESMKKBlbf2b4ql_hWZbskgu%26client_secret%3D4869032460675835042%26username%3Dpkonda%2540cardlytics.com.dev%26password%3DAppleJack_2019">Forgot Your Password?</a>
                                    <a id="mydomainLink" class="fr small" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="DomainSwitcher.enterCustomDomain('Use Custom Domain',' | Salesforce')">Use Custom Domain</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div id="mydomainContainer" style="display:none;">
                                <p class="mb16">To go to your company's login page, enter the custom domain name.</p>
                                <form onsubmit="DomainSwitcher.handleMyDomain();return false;">
                                    <label for="mydomain" class="label">Custom Domain</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="input wide focus mt8 mb16" name="mydomain" id="mydomain" onkeyup="DomainSwitcher.updateMyDomain(this, event);"/>
                                    <div id="mydomain_preview" class="mb16 wordwrap">https://
                                        <em>domain</em>.my.salesforce.com
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                                <input type="hidden" id="mydomain_suffix" value=".my.salesforce.com"/>
                                <input type="hidden" id="community_suffix" value=".ap3.force.com"/>
                                <button class="button primary fiftyfifty right" id="mydomainContinue" name="Continue" onclick="DomainSwitcher.handleMyDomain();">Continue</button>
                                <button class="button secondary fiftyfifty" id="hint_back_domain" onclick="DomainSwitcher.dismissCustomDomain('Login',' | Salesforce');">Back</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="signup" class="tc mt24">
                            <p class="di mr16">Not a customer?</p>
                            <a class="button secondary" id="signup_link" href="https://www.salesforce.com/form/trial/freetrial.jsp?d=70130000000Enus">Try for Free</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tc" id="use_new_identity_div" style="display:none;">
                            <a id="use_new_identity" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="LoginHint.useNewIdentity();">Log In with a Different Username</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">&copy; 2019 salesforce.com, inc. All rights reserved. | 
                <a id="privacy-link" href="https://www.salesforce.com/us/company/privacy" target="_blank">Privacy</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <iframe frameborder="0" src="/s.gif" id="marketing" name="marketing" scrolling="no" title="Marketing" tabindex="-1"sandbox="allow-forms allow-pointer-lock allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts" ></iframe>
        </div>
        <div aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" class="zen-assistiveText" style="width:0px;height:0px;" id="assistive-announce">Login</div>
        <script>LoginHint.getSavedIdentities(false);</script>
        <script src="/jslibrary/baselogin4.js"></script>
        <script src="/jslibrary/LoginMarketingSurveyResponse.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/marketing/survey/survey1/1380"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/marketing/survey/survey4/1380"></script>
        <script>function handleLogin(){document.login.un.value=document.login.username.value;document.login.width.value=screen.width;document.login.height.value=screen.height;}function lazyload(){document.getElementById("pwcapsicon").src="/img/icon/capslock_blue.png";document.getElementById("marketing").src="https://c.salesforce.com/login-messages/promos.html";}loader();</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the request URL?

Comment: I'm using this "https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token". I did not find anything different for Sandbox so using the same

Comment: Is this sandbox (as you have mentioned)? If yes, then you need to use test.salesforce.com instead of login.salesforce.com

Comment: I just tried. No change in the response.

Comment: When I pass client_id, secret, username and password in the body instead of query parameters, I'm getting a response saying Bad Requet and the message as unsupported grant type

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/263202/edit) and provide the complete request details? Make sure not to expose any credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below s what your `POST` request should look like.Please note the password might need the password+token concatenated:

Endpoint: `https://XXXXX.my.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token`

```
Request Body:

client_id: lorem-ipsum-a
client_secret: lorem-ipsum-b
username: lorem-ipsum-c
password: lorem-ipsum-d //**NOTE YOU MIGHT NEED TO DO PASSWORD+TOKEN**
grant_type:password
```

Comment: They are *not* headers.

Comment: no, they are definitely not headers. thanks for catching that

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass in your parameters in the body. The request going over the wire should look like this:

```
POST /services/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.salesforce.com
Content-Length: ###
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: application/json

grant_type=password&username=abc%40xyz.com&password=mysecretpassword&client_id=####&client_secret=####
```

All parameters must be encoded, Content-Length must be correct, Content-Type is optional. If you are using the query string, the request **will** be invalid. It must be in the body of the request. Also, double-check that the URL is correct, as this may cause problems.

Please check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_username_password_oauth_flow.htm) for additional information.